# Including specific property in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of code that appends suffixes to inputs. So users have an easier time with em vs. px. I am running into a slight issue though.

I am including the properties with an array and looping through them to see what fields need suffixes and what suffixes they need. This was working fine until I needed to change a property "border-width" to px instead of em, but keep width em's. Does this make sense?

Basically, I need to include the border-width field in my exceptions without including width.

My jQuery looks like this

```
 var valueArray = ["padding", "width", "Width", "height", "Height"];

for(var i = 0, ii = valueArray.length; i < ii; i++){
    if ($("input[name*='" + valueArray[i] + "']").attr('name') === 'kiosk_height' || $("input[name*='" + valueArray[i] + "']").attr('name') === 'kiosk_width' || $("input[name*='" + valueArray[i] + "']").attr('name') === 'border-width'){
        $("input[name*='" + valueArray[i] + "']").on("focusout", function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if(value.indexOf("em") <= 0 && value.indexOf("px") <= 0 && value.indexOf("%") <= 0 && $(this).val().length != 0){
                var newVal = value + 'px';
                $(this).val(newVal).trigger('change');
            }
        });
    }else{
        $("input[name*='" + valueArray[i] + "']").on("focusout", function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value.indexOf("em") <= 0 && value.indexOf("px") <= 0 && value.indexOf("%") <= 0 && $(this).val().length != 0) {
                var newVal = value + 'em';
                $(this).val(newVal).trigger('change');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the jsFiddle I created that includes the html. 
https://jsfiddle.net/q3b0t8af/2/

I cannot change the html around, I am stuck using the name field to call out specific fields.

Comment: You should avoid using `functions` within `loops`, and use `!==` to compare

Comment: @YosvelQuintero Then what would be a better way to accomplish this?

And those are the properties I want to equal the px. Are you saying to flip my if statement?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want. Could you provide us more information, like what you wish to do and what is your expected result?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I have input fields that if you enter a value in and click off it adds a 'px' or 'em' after the value. You can see this happening in my jsFiddle. I have two fields that share a word "width" and "border-width" so they are both appending the same value, but I need "width" to append "em" and "border-width" to append "px"

Answer (score 0):

Made this for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/q3b0t8af/3/

All you have to do is to use a array of exclusion:

```
var valueArray = ["padding", "width", "Width", "height", "Height"];
var exceptionArray = ['kiosk_height','kiosk_width','border-width'];

$.each($("input"), function(i,v){
     if ($(v).attr('name') != undefined && $.inArray($(v).attr('name').trim(), exceptionArray) > -1) {
         $(v).on("focusout", function() {
             var value = $(this).val();
             if (value.indexOf("em") <= 0 && value.indexOf("px") <= 0 && value.indexOf("%") <= 0 && $(this).val().length != 0) {
                 var newVal = value + 'px';
             }
             $(this).val(newVal).trigger('change');
         });
     } else {
         $(v).on("focusout", function() {
             var value = $(this).val();
             if (value.indexOf("em") <= 0 && value.indexOf("px") <= 0 && value.indexOf("%") <= 0 && $(this).val().length != 0) {
                 var newVal = value + 'em';
                 $(this).val(newVal).trigger('change');
             }
         });
     }
});
```

Comment: The only issue it I need the only fields on the page to match what is in the valueArray. I have some 100 properties on the page and this is going to affect color pickers, checkboxes and fields where they enter words.

Comment: Replace `$("input")` with something more useful for you, like `$.each([$("input[name*='padding']"), $("input[name='width ']"), $("input[name='height']"), $("input[name='border-width ']")], function(i,v){`

Comment: That creates the same issue though where border-width and width cannot be different

Comment: Don't use `input[name*=`, use `input[name=` instead, without `*`

Answer (score 0):

Is being more explicit with your "em" and "px" selectors an option? Then this would work (also cleaned up the code a bit).

```
var emArray = ["padding", "padding-left", "padding-right ", 
               "padding-bottom", "padding-top ", "width ", "height"];
var pxArray = ["border-width ", "kiosk_height", "kiosk_width"];

for (var i=0; i < emArray.length; i++)
    $("input[name='" + emArray[i] + "']").on("focusout", {unit:'em'}, dostuff);
for (var i=0; i < pxArray.length; i++)
    $("input[name='" + pxArray[i] + "']").on("focusout", {unit:'px'}, dostuff);

function dostuff(event) {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var unit = event.data.unit;

  if (value.indexOf("em") <= 0 && value.indexOf("px") <= 0 && 
      value.indexOf("%") <= 0 && $(this).val().length != 0) {
    $(this).val(value + unit).trigger('change');
  }
}
```